# why item context menu is not showing up in listview

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-arrayadapter, contextmenu

I'm working on a listview with context menu for every item in the listview; however, when clicking on an item the context menu doesn't show. I have created a list_menu.xml file under menu directory, and I'm using a custom adapter. The custom adapter xml file consist of an image and textview. Eventually, I would like to show the menu when clicking on the image, but for now, I would like to show the menu when clicking on a list item. But nothing happens. How can I make the context menu show? thanks
main xml

```
package org.pctechtips.menulistview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList hosts;
    String ipAdd = "192.168.10.";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hosts = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            hosts.add(ipAdd+i);
        }

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.ip_address, hosts);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(list);

    }

    /*
    * Infating the menu for toolbar
    */
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
    }
}
```

adapter

```
package org.pctechtips.menulistview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.pctechtips.menulistview.R.drawable.computer_48_dp;

/**
 * Created by George on 8/8/2017.
 */

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int num, ArrayList<String> hosts) {
        super(context, 0, hosts);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        String item = getItem(position);

        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        ImageView iconImgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.host_icon);
        TextView ipAddTxtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ip_address);


        iconImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.computer_48_dp);
        ipAddTxtView.setText(item);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

list_item xml file (adapter)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/host_icon"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/computer_48_dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ip_address"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.80"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            tools:text="192.168.10.100"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

list_menu.xml file

```
 <!-- listview menu for host scan options eg:
         change hostname, icon, notification etc -->
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/change_icon"
    android:title="change icon"
    />

<item android:id="@+id/set_hostname"
    android:title="set hostname"
    />

<itme android:id="@+id/notifications"
    android:title="notifications"
     />

</menu>
```

Comment: Context menu work on long press of list item rather than click. Have you tried that?

Comment: lol... ok it works... so I guess I would have to use a popup menu?

Comment: You can open the context menu on short click as well. Have a look at my answer on how to do it.

Comment: is the type of menu in this pic context menu?

Comment: please add the pic :)

Comment: this is the menu I was referring to http://pctechtips.org/pics/android_listview_menu.png

Comment: yep this can be done using context menu

Comment: but this is a short click, plus how do I get the 3 dots on every item in listview

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer below. add the three dots as an image in listview and then just click on it to open it.

Comment: I have been looking for the 3 image all over, can you point me somewhere? thanks

Comment: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=more_vert&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_more_vert&theme=light&color=rgba(33%2C%20150%2C%20243%2C%200.6)

Comment: ideally you can do this with popup menu as well which i think will be a neater option as it involves list.

Comment: have update my answer below for popup menu as well. and most icons you can find here http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: thanks buddy appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context menu work on long press of list item rather than short click. If you want it to work on short click implement `onListItemClick` method as below

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
  list.showContextMenuForChild(v);   
}
```

If you want to open the same on some other element like a button you can do as -

```
public void onButtonClickEvent(View sender)
{
    registerForContextMenu(sender); 
    openContextMenu(sender);
    unregisterForContextMenu(sender);
}
```

Otherwise you can also use `PopupMenu`

add in layout in listview item as -

```
<ImageButton
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_overflow_holo_dark"
   android:contentDescription="@string/descr_overflow_button"
   android:onClick="showPopup" />
```

Then implement your showPopup method as below -

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
     PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
     MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
     popup.show();
 }
```

Comment: can I invoke the menu by pressing on an image inside listview item? I guess instead of using a button I have to use the image as click listener

Comment: Yes instead of button use an image clicklistener

Comment: do I need to register popup menu with listview? is there any methods I need to use when inflating listview like for context menu registerForContextMenu(list);? thanks

Comment: You do it onclick so no need to register

Comment: Try it out and if you face any issue, we all are here to help :)

Comment: why do I only get two items in my menu, eventhough my list_menu.xml has three?

Comment: Not sure. Need to see the code to understand it. You can raise another question for it so that more people have visibility and everyone can answer that :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `PopupMenu` is for item click, for long click use `ContextMenu`,

```
   convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, v);
               //Inflating popup menu
               popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
               //add OnMenuItemClickListener to popup
               popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       return true;
                   }
               });

               popup.show();
```

Comment: do I need to register the popup menu with listview?